# Unexpected 0 appearing in a list despite the code seemingly preventing a zero from being added to the list

Tags: python, list, function, class, min

I'm working on a tile based game in Python. For some reason, my function that finds the distance (in tile spaces) from a specified tile and the closest water tile, keeps returning 0 if the specified tile isn't the top left tile or adjacent to it. The function should normally only return 0 if the specified tile itself is a water tile. I tested the top left tile even when it was water and it still returns 0 in that case like its supposed to, and of course works properly with any other edits to the tiles around it. Like I said however, any tile that is tested which isn't adjacent to the top left tile never works no matter what the circumstance, it always returns 0.

The reason 0 shouldn't ever show up if I test a non-water tile is that the function appends the distances of a tile being tested relative to all water tiles to a list and then finds the minimum of that list and returns it. Since a non-water tile won't be in the list of water tiles, there should never be a case where is measures the distance between the specified tile and itself which would result in a 0. I did some self testing and confirmed that the water tiles list does indeed only contain the coordinates of water tiles, and the specified tile is of course specified in the function so there can't be error there.

Below is my code. It was originally written in codeskulptor and used the random module and simplegui module, but since this question doesn't involve either of those i stripped them away. I also cut out all the code which isn't relevant to this problem so don't worry about trying to point out other potential problems I might run into trying to do what I do. I also deeply apologize for the terrible naming conventions. I adapted the code to work in Pycharm so that more people might be able to diagnose it. Thanks so much.

Edit: It's come to my attention that I'm talking as though there is physical space being produced by this code, when there actually isn't in this version. I'll give you some reference points:

-tiles[0] would be at the top left

-tiles[1] would be to the right of tiles[0]

-tiles[80] would be right under tiles[0] because each row is 80 tiles

Furthermore, the function in question is "distance_from_water" near the top.

```
def distance(tile1, tile2):
    # returns the distance of two tiles
    return abs((tile2.x - tile1.x) + (tile2.y - tile1.y))


def distance_from_water(tile, index):
    # cycles through every water tile and adds the distances
    # of them relative to a specified tile to a list, then returns
    # the lowest distance
    water_tiles = []
    water_tile_proximities = []
    for element in range(0, len(index)):
        if index[element].iswater == True:
            water_tiles.append(element)
    for element in water_tiles:
        water_tile_proximities.append(distance(index[tile], index[element]))
    lowest_distance = min(water_tile_proximities)
    return lowest_distance


canvaswidth = 1280
canvasheight = 800

tile_size = 16
tile_slots = int((canvaswidth / tile_size) * (canvasheight / tile_size))
tile_slot_locations = [[(tile_size / 2), (tile_size / 2)]]

for element in range(0, (tile_slots - 1)):
    # finds how many discrete locations for tiles there are based on the canvas size
    if tile_slot_locations[element][0] > (canvaswidth - (tile_size / 2)):
        tile_slot_locations[element][0] = (tile_size / 2)
        tile_slot_locations[element][1] += tile_size
    tile_slot_locations.append([((tile_slot_locations[element][0]) + tile_size), tile_slot_locations[element][1]])
tiles = []
colors = ["blue", "green", "darkgreen", "grey", "khaki", "brown"]


class Tile(object):
    list_of_all_tiles = []

    def __init__(self, location, color):
        self.location = location
        self.color = color
        self.dimensions = ((location[0] + (tile_size / 2), location[1] + (tile_size / 2)),
                           (location[0] + (tile_size / 2), location[1] - (tile_size / 2)),
                           (location[0] - (tile_size / 2), location[1] - (tile_size / 2)),
                           (location[0] - (tile_size / 2), location[1] + (tile_size / 2)),
                           (location[0] + (tile_size / 2), location[1] + (tile_size / 2)))
        self.x = (location[0] - (tile_size / 2)) / tile_size
        self.y = (location[1] - (tile_size / 2)) / tile_size
        Tile.list_of_all_tiles.append(self)
        # determine the type
        if color == "blue":
            self.iswater = True
            self.island = False
            self.isforest = False
            self.ismountain = False
            self.issand = False
            self.isinn = False
        if color == "green":
            self.iswater = False
            self.island = True
            self.isforest = False
            self.ismountain = False
            self.issand = False
            self.isinn = False
        if color == "darkgreen":
            self.iswater = False
            self.island = False
            self.isforest = True
            self.ismountain = False
            self.issand = False
            self.isinn = False
        if color == "grey":
            self.iswater = False
            self.island = False
            self.isforest = False
            self.ismountain = True
            self.issand = False
            self.isinn = False
        if color == "khaki":
            self.iswater = False
            self.island = False
            self.isforest = False
            self.ismountain = False
            self.issand = True
            self.isinn = False
        if color == "brown":
            self.iswater = False
            self.island = False
            self.isforest = False
            self.ismountain = False
            self.issand = False
            self.isinn = True


for element in range(0, len(tile_slot_locations)):
    # cycles through and assigns the Tile class
    # using every tile slot location and saves in "tiles" list
    tile = Tile(tile_slot_locations[element], colors[0])
    tiles.append(tile)

tiles[120].island = True
tiles[120].iswater = False
tiles[1].island = True
tiles[1].iswater = False
tiles[80].island = True
tiles[80].iswater = False
tiles[81].island = True
tiles[81].iswater = False
tiles[3].island = True
tiles[3].iswater = False

print(distance_from_water(3, tiles))
```

Comment: You really need to narrow this down. This is a lot of code to have us look through. What function are you talking about? The second distance one?

Comment: Based on the answer this is exactly the kind of problem a walk through the debugger would easily uncover. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/) and [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BixeKmlKOJc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `distance()` function is fundamentally broken - it's quite capable of returning a zero distance for tiles that are arbitrarily far apart, if their X difference is the negative of their Y difference.  The expression should be:

```
abs(tile2.x - tile1.x) + abs(tile2.y - tile1.y)
```

instead of:

```
abs((tile2.x - tile1.x) + (tile2.y - tile1.y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the distance is not your only problem. a very similar bug is

```
tile_slots = int((canvaswidth / tile_size) * (canvasheight / tile_size))
```

where you most probably want

```
tile_slots = int(canvaswidth / tile_size) * int(canvasheight / tile_size)
```

which in python3 you write

```
tile_slots = (canvaswidth // tile_size) * (canvasheight // tile_size)
```

---

some more hints

while i do not think your tile representation is ideal you can shorten the determine type block massively

```
# determine the type
self.iswater    = color == "blue"
self.island     = color == "green"
self.isforest   = color == "darkgreen"
self.ismountain = color == "grey"
self.issand     = color == "khaki"
self.isinn      = color == "brown"
```